# Why is the repo size still big after using BFG but cloning size is much smaller

Tags: git, bitbucket, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have used BFG to remove a lot of big files from a repository and have reduced the "Receiving objects" when cloning to 206MB from 1.18GiB.

But when I look in Bitbucket (Self hosted) and use its Approximate size
feature, the old repo is 1100MB and the new is 1000MB, so the 1/6 size reduction in cloning is not represented at all here.

Is there a way to determine what is taking up the space on the origin repository?

Comment: Garbage collection probably still has not happened on the server, so the old commits are still there. There might also be an event history (like on GitHub, though I don't know if Bitbucket has that too) preventing your old commits from being collected.

Comment: @joanis It has been several days now and its still big. Also I renamed the old repository and pushed the cleaned up one to a fresh repository

Comment: Several days is a very short time. I'm pretty sure it takes a couple weeks or more. Think of it as a backup retention policy. The event log might even keep old commits in there for months... Pushing to a fresh repo is a good call.

Comment: You could try logging onto the bitbucket server, locating the repo on disk (you can find the repo path under settings in Bitbucket). Then if you run `git repack -a -f -d`, it should tidy things up.

Comment: I am facing this issue too, can you confirm whether the size of your repo eventually gets smaller?